# Is it possible to run cdk commands from an IAM role?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy aws-cdk infrastructure as code from a jenkins pipeline but it requires aws credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials`.

The server running jenkins was provided with an IAM role with enough permissions to deploy any type of ressource. I have also tried passing env variables to provide it with the correct regions and account: `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=XXX` `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2`.

This is my current stage

```
        stage('Deploy test infrastructure') {
          container(cdkDeployContainer.getName()) {
            sh("npm install -g aws-cdk aws-cli")
            sh("cd test-infrastructure && npm install && CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=154438573167 CDK_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2 cdk bootstrap")
          }
        }
```

I am receiving this error `Unable to determine default account and/or region` Is it possible to use a role IAM while using the CDK? what are the other alternatives to providing an IAM programatic access key?

Answer (score 19):

It is possible. You just need to assume the role. Here's how you can do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export ACCOUNT_ID="154438573167"
role_arn="arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/jenkins-deploy-role"

export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-2"
KST=($(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "${role_arn}" --role-session-name jenkins --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]' --output text))
unset AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${KST[0]}
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${KST[1]}
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${KST[2]}
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=${KST[2]}

# Now you have assumed the role and obtained temporary credentials.
cdk bootstrap
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `--role-arn` parameter of the cdk cli to assume a role.

for example:

```
cdk deploy --role-arn arn:aws:iam::01234567890:role/jenkins-deploy-role
```